# What is a casual way of saying "I will go offline soon" in an Internet conversation

Tags: conversation

I'm having a conversation on my phone, but know I can't answer in a short while (e. g. need to go to sleep of have an appointment). What's a casual way of saying "I'm going offline soon"? I wanted to say "I'll have to tune off in 5 min" but apparently that's not a valid phrase.

With smartphones everyone is online 24/7, so saying "I'm going offline" is technically wrong, it doesn't feel polite and it doesn't sound like something a teen would casually say.

Another example: I'm having an online chat but want to focus on school work. I'm not going offline, but I want to focus on the school work instead of the conversation.

Comment: It doesn't hurt to say why you have to go: "Turning in soon...Talk tomorrow."

Comment: Hey, I gotta run.  Ttyl.  Or “Gotta go. Catch ya later”  or I’ve got about 5mins left then I need to go.”  Etc

Comment: What would you say if it was a phone conversation? Apart from "I've got to hang up / ring off now" which are specific to ordinary phone calls and which I, for one, use very rarely. "Sorry, got to go now" is applicable to any medium including a physical encounter. Any technological phrases such as, "ring off", "log out", "shut down"" and so on are merely medium-specific additions to "got to go" and its variations.

Comment: *"With smartphones everyone is online 24/7"* - No they're not. People still sleep. Lots of people turn their phone off or set it on silent when going to bed or in meetings, at the cinema, etc.